# How to change perfmon time axis interval

Tags: perfmon, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to measure some counters using `perfmon.exe` on Windows Server 2012 R2. The default interval of time is only one minute, but I would like to measure for a couple of hours but I can't find the option to change it. Any hints, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission, you can create a Data Collector Set. Apart from several options, you can define the stop condition on a time basis or on the size of the log collected.